# how to fix the color of the button when ng-click done using ng-storage?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have the two buttons. Defullt color of the buttos is green. when first time cilck on button the color of the button will move to red. but when refreshing the the color of the buttons will go to the default color. 
please help me how to make the color of the buttons stranded when refreshing the page.

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', ["ngStorage"]);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$localStorage) {
  $scope.tablelist = [{"tablename":"t1"},{"tablename":"t2"}]
  if($localStorage.tableArray === undefined){
      $localStorage.tableArray = []
      }
  if($localStorage.tableslist===undefined){
      $localStorage.tableslist=[]
      }
  $scope.getTable=function(table){
  table.btnClass = table.btnClass == "btn-danger" ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger"
  var exists=false;
  angular.forEach($localStorage.tableArray, function (list,$index) {
    if ((list.tablename == table.tablename)) {
        console.log(list.tablename)
         console.log(table.tablename)
        exists=true;
        $localStorage.tableArray.splice($index,1)
        $localStorage.tableArray.splice($index,1)
        return false
    }
 });
 if(!exists){
      $localStorage.tableslist.push(table)
      $localStorage.tableArray=$localStorage.tableslist;
      $scope.$storage=$localStorage.tableArray
      console.log($localStorage.tableArray)
      table.color="red"
          }
     } 
});
```

`https://plnkr.co/edit/pSld7q89t1DCZ6l4pglZ?p=preview

Comment: When Refreshing the page, it displays in Green..What actually you wanna do??

Comment: when click on button color change to red. now i refresh the page the color  of button should be red.

Comment: You can do it via `AJAX` if you wanna save into Server or use `localStorage` to reflect the same only within local Computer.

Comment: please provide any sample code, plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearing storage data in `$localStorage.tableArray` every time click
event fires, so you have to pass the stored cssClass from that array to  `$scope.tablelist` before clearing it. It worked with me by doing the following:

1- add $filter to controller:

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $localStorage, $filter) {
```

2- add following code before `$scope.getTable = function`:

```
angular.forEach($scope.tablelist, function (list, $index) 
{
  var found = $filter('filter')($localStorage.tableArray, 
              { tablename: list.tablename }, true);

  if (found.length) {$scope.tablelist[$index].btnClass = found[0].btnClass;}
});
```

> EDIT: 
>   This is the plnkr link:
>   https://plnkr.co/edit/x32vQIJO6wbzZjDa77WH?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your Response. This is not working for me. can you please edit the code in the plunker.

Comment: I added the link in my answer

Comment: Thank you So much @user2903753.